# What is determined by the combinatorics of the shadows of a convex polyhedron?

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes

Define the *shadow* of a convex polyhedron $P$ in direction $u$
to be the orthogonal projection of $P$ onto a plane whose normal is $u$.
The shadow is a convex $k$-gon.
I am wondering to what degree $P$ is determined by knowing
the value of $k$ for all the distinct shadows.
Let me try to make precise what I mean by "the combinatorics of the shadows."

On a unit sphere $S$, mark all the directions parallel to a face
of $P$.  Equivalently, intersect $S$ with planes through its
center parallel to each face of $P$.
Here is the result for a regular tetrahedron:

[image: Sphere]

Each cell $c$ of this arrangement of great circles corresponds to
a distinct shadow in the sense that, for all $u \in c$,
the shadow in direction $u$ is a $k$-gon, with $k$ fixed.
In this example, the shadows for a cell are either triangles or quadrilaterals,
3-gons or 4-gons.

Now form a graph, the *shadow graph* $G_S$, the dual graph of
the arrangement: each node is a cell, with an edge connecting
cells that share a positive-length arc.
Label each node with the integer $k \ge 3$ if that cell's
shadows are $k$-gons.
For the tetrahedron example, $G_S$ has 14 nodes,
labeled as shown below:

                  [image: Graph]

Now imagine you are given the labeled $G_S$ as input.  I would like to
know to what extent $P$ is determined.

> (1) Does this arrangement and/or its dual graph have a name in the literature?
>   I've seen the term *Gaussian sphere* in the early computer vision literature,
>   but that term is not prevalent.  I feel I may be missing a key search phrase.
>
> (2) Does $G_S$ determine $V$, $E$, and $F$, the number of vertices,
>   edges, and faces of $P$, i.e., the $f$-vector?
>
> (3) Given $G_S$, can you find some representative $P$ that realizes those combinatorics?
>
> (4) More generally, what is the class of $P$ that realizes a given $G_S$?
>
> (4a) A very specific version of this question is: Are all the $P$ that
>   yield the $G_S$ illustrated above tetrahedra?
>
> (5) The question generalizes to polytopes in $\mathbb{R}^d$, which
>   is the root of my question.

Perhaps some of these questions are easier under genericity assumptions,
e.g., no two faces are parallel.
**Edit**. For example, under the assumption that no three faces
are parallel to a line (which implies no two faces are parallel [thanks to Giovanni Viglietta for the correction]), $G_S$ has $m=F^2-F+2$ nodes for $F$ faces,
so $F=\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{ 4m -7})$, which partially solves (2) above.

I'd appreciate pointers to relevant literature!

Comment: See related question (at the end of) http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39127/is-the-sphere-the-only-surface-all-of-whose-projections-are-circles-or-can-we-d To what extent are surfaces determined by their projections?

Comment: I believe your sample graph has a mistake:  for reasons of 
symmetry, the lower left and lower right edges should connect
to the 4's on the two sides, not to the 3's.

Comment: @Bill: Whoops, you are correct! Fixed now.

Comment: How do you define "shadow graph" if not all faces are triangles?

Comment: @Anton: For example, for a cube, the sphere gets cut into eight octants, each becomes a node of degree three, and each cell of this
arrangement gets labeled "6" because the shadows are hexagons.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't directly answer your question, I fear, but it's at least tangentially related.  Suppose we keep slightly more information than the combinatorics of $G_S$, and label each node as well with the *area* of the corresponding cell on the sphere.  Let $A$ be the sum of the areas corresponding to nodes originally labeled "3" (where the projection is a triangle), and $T$ be the sum of the areas of all nodes.  Then it's shown in "Angles as Probabilities" by David V. Feldman and Daniel A. Klain, *American Mathematical Monthly*, [October 2009](http://www.maa.org/pubs/monthly_oct09_toc.html), that $2\pi A/T$ is the sum of the solid inner angles of the vertices of the original tetrahedron -- that is, you can interpret that angle sum as the probability that an orthogonal projection to a random plane is a triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another tangentially-related answer.  There is a nice characterization of "equiprojective polyhedra" due to Masud Hasan and Anna Libiw.  (A convex polyhedron is "equiprojective" if, for some $k$, the general shadow is a $k$-gon.)

Comment: Yes, thanks David! For example, a cube is 6-equiprojective: all the nodes would be labeled "6" in $G_S$. They recently proved that any equiprojective polyhedron has at least one pair of parallel faces. They have a new arXiv paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.2252 