# A wild embedding of $\mathbb{S}^1$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, embeddings

> Can one construct an embedding of $\mathbb{S}^1$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$
>   so that **every** orthogonal projection onto a two dimensional plane
>   is a unit disc?

It is easy to construct an embedding of $\mathbb{S}^1$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ so that one orthogonal projection is a unit disc: take a Peano-type curve $\gamma=(\gamma_1,\gamma_2):[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ that fills the unit disc and define
$\Gamma(t)=(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t),t):[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^3$. Clearly $\Gamma$ is one-to-one so it is an embedding and its projection onto the first two coordinates fills the disc. It remains now to "glue" the ends to make it an embedding of $\mathbb{S}^1$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No.

Assume it is possible, that is, there is an embedding $f\colon\mathbb{S}^1\to \mathbb R^3$ such that any projection of $f(\mathbb{S}^1)$ is a unit disc.

By [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/39131/1441), the convex hull of the image $f(\mathbb{S}^1)$ is a unit ball.
Further note that every extreme point lies in the image;
that is, $f(\mathbb{S}^1)\supset\mathbb{S}^2$ --- a contradiction.

**P.S.** There are embeddings $f\colon\mathbb{S}^1\to \mathbb R^3$ such that any projection of $f(\mathbb{S}^1)$ contains a unit disc.
Moreover one can assume that the convex hull $W=\mathop{\rm Conv}f(\mathbb{S}^1)$ is arbitrary close to the unit ball. 
(Typically, the set of extreme points of $W$ is a Cantor set.)
To construct $f$, modify a space filling curve by making it injective, but still intersecting all the lines pass thru the unit ball.

Comment: Add the link to this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39127/is-the-sphere-the-only-surface-all-of-whose-projections-are-circles-or-can-we

Comment: @TarasBanakh Thank you for the link. It greatly complements Anton's answer.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz You are welcome.

Comment: This answer is (was) completely impossible to understand if one does not click the link "is a unit ball", I spent 5 minutes puzzled before clicking... I rephrased to emphasize that this is the main point, not just "note that".

Comment: What if we only ask for every projection to contain a disk? i.e. have nonempty interior?

Comment: @Wojowu see the postscript.