# Recovering a set from its projections in varying coordinate systems - a projection hull?

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, gn.general-topology, lie-groups, plane-geometry

Let me describe the simplest non-trivial case of what I have in mind. Let $V$ be a 2-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space and fix an isomorphism $V \cong \mathbb{R}^2$, where $\mathbb{R}^2$ is equipped with the standard basis. This will be our starting frame of reference, so to speak. Let $S \subseteq V$ be an arbitrary subset. I am mostly interested in the cases where $S$ is a path, or a loop, or an open subset, but **for the purpose of this question let me give a formulation for the case when $S := U$ is an open subset of the plane.**

Let $I \in \operatorname{M}_2(\mathbb{R}) \cong \operatorname{End}(V)$ denote the identity matrix, let $p_I : U \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the projection onto, say, the *first* coordinate with respect to the standard basis (hence the $I$-notation), and define
$$
U_I := p_I(U) \times \mathbb{R}.
$$
(It won't matter if we choose the first or the second projection.) Clearly, $U_I \supseteq U$ is the best we can recover from only knowing $p_I(U)$. Now change the basis (coordinate system) via $(A^T)^{-1} \in \operatorname{GL}_2^+(\mathbb{R})$ and put similarly
$$
U_A := p_A(U) \times \mathbb{R},
$$
where $p_A : U \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the projection onto the *first* coordinate with respect to the new basis.
Define the *projection hull* (for a lack of a better term) of $U$ to be
$$
\tilde{U} = \bigcap_{A \in \operatorname{GL}_2^+(\mathbb{R})} U_A
$$
Then $\tilde{U} \supseteq U$ is the best we can recover from knowing the 1-dimensional projection of $U$ in every coordinate system.

Of course, one can do a similar construction with $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and both projections, which produces the same result by rotation invariance of the problem, or one may consider more special types of coordinate changes, i.e. other subgroups of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Here is an explicit description of the set $U_A$ with respect to the original frame of reference:
$$
U_A = \bigg\{ \frac{1}{\det(A)} (a_{11} a_{22} x_1 + a_{12} a_{22} x_2 - a_{12}y, -a_{11} a_{21} x_1 - a_{12} a_{21} x_2 + a_{11} y) \mid (x_1,x_2) \in U, y \in \mathbb{R} \bigg\}
$$
where $a_{11},a_{12},a_{21},a_{22}$ are the coefficients of $A$. (I sincerely hope I haven't miscalculated or mistyped.)

Here are my questions:

**(Q1)** Is there an accepted name for $\tilde{U}$ in the literature?

**(Q2)** Assuming $U$ is a **bounded simply connected domain**, can we have $\tilde{U} \supsetneqq U$? If yes, is there a different, more tangible characterization of $\tilde{U}$?

*Please feel free to add more appropriate tags.*

Comment: See also the related further questions mentioned in https://mathoverflow.net/q/39127/1946 and several interesting answers, including one by Bill Thurston.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: Thanks! I will check it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\tU}{\tilde U}$Suppose that $U$ is connected. Then all its projections are connected. So, all one-dimensional projections of $U$ will be convex. So, $\tilde U$ will be convex.

Now take any non-convex connected $U$. Then $\tilde U\ne U$ and hence $\tilde{U} \supsetneqq U$.

---

Suppose now that a connected subset $U$ of $\R^2$ is closed and bounded. Then
\begin{equation}
    \tU=\bigcap_{l\in(\R^2)'}l^{-1}([m_l,M_l]),
\end{equation}
where $(\R^2)'$ is the space of all linear functionals on $\R^2$, $m_l:=\min l(U)$, and $M_l:=\max l(U)$.

Let us show that
$$\tU=C,$$
the closed convex hull of $U$. (So, is then a new name for $\tU$ needed?)

Clearly $\tU$ contains $U$ and is closed and convex, as the intersection of closed convex sets. So, $C\subseteq\tU$.

To obtain a contradiction, assume that $\tU\not\subseteq C$. So, we have some $x\in\tU\setminus C$. Then $x$ can be separated from $C$ by some $l_x\in(\R^2)'$ so that $l_x(x)<\min l_x(C)\le\min l_x(U)=m_{l_x}$. Then $x\notin l_x^{-1}([m_{l_x},M_{l_x}])$, which contradicts the condition $x\in\tU$. So, $\tU\subseteq C\subseteq\tU$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: Thanks, nice catch on the convexity! So, $\tilde{U}$ will contain the convex hull of $U$. Is it clear that it could be strictly larger than the convex hull, though? It seems plausible to conjecture that they may in fact coincide.

Comment: @M.G. : Yes, it is now shown that, if $U$ is closed and bounded, then $\tilde{U}$ is the closed convex hull of $U$.

Comment: Very nice and very helpful! Thank you for the grear answer!

Answer (score 1):

Your definition is a special case of the following. Choose some set $S$ whose elements are subsets of $V$. Say that a subset of $V$ is $S$-convex if it is the intersection of some elements of $S$. The $S$-hull of a set $U$ is the smallest $S$-convex set containing $U$, i.e. the intersection of all the elements of $S$ that contain $U$.

For you the elements of $S$ are the sets $\varphi^{-1}(\mathbb R\backslash \{a\})$ where $\varphi$ is a non-zero element of $V^\ast$ and $a\in \mathbb R$, i.e. the complements of the affine hyperplanes in $V$.

If instead we choose $S$ to consist of the closed half-spaces $\varphi^{-1}([a,\infty))$, then $S$-convex means convex and closed. Or if we choose $S$ to consist of the open half-spaces then $S$-convex means something else, stronger than convex; let's call it "strongly convex".

As observed by Pinelis, if $U$ is connected and closed and bounded then your $\tilde U$ is the (closed) convex hull. More generally if $U$ is connected then $\tilde U$ is the strongly convex hull.

More generally, if $U$ cannot be separated into two nonempty pieces by any hyperplane then $\tilde U$ is the strongly convex hull.

$U$ is equal to $\tilde U$ if $U$ is empty, or if $U$ is a nonempty strongly convex set, or if $U$ is the union of two sets of that kind that can be separated by some hyperplane, or if $U$ is the union of three sets of that kind such that each of them can be separated from the other two by a hyperplane, "and so on".

Comment: Thank you very much for prividing some additional context to my question! I just tried googling "S-convex" (and similar) and it returned a lot of related material. Sometimes it is really a question of knowing the right keyword.

Comment: You're welcome. I just invented the term S-convex. I've pondered your question about complex "convexity", without coming up with much. There, of course, the generating set S consists of the complements of complex hyperplanes.

Comment: Oh, thanks for warning me, so the results Google returned are unfortunately likely unrelated, i.e. the term has different meanings depending on contexts. Also, thank you for considering the complex version, it's probably more subtle already for topological reasons, for ex. the projection need no longer be simply connected. Its origin is SCVs (carrying additional structures), so I suspect that a "conventional" characterization might be of a very different flavour than the real case.