# Characterization of a "complex" hull?

Tags: linear-algebra, gn.general-topology, convex-analysis, several-complex-variables

This is a complex continuation of [my previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447067/recovering-a-set-from-its-projections-in-varying-coordinate-systems-a-projecti). There Iosif Pinelis showed that the so obtained closure from taking the intersection of the preimages of the linear functionals indeed coincides with the (closed) convex hull of the set. I want to ask the analogous question for the complex case and I will use his formulation because I like it conceptually much better than mine :-)

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, $\dim_\mathbb{C} V \geq 2$, and let $U \subseteq V$ be a subset. I am mostly interested in the case $U$ being a domain (i.e. open and connected), bounded or not, but feel free to consider its closure $\bar{U}$ instead. Define the *complex hull* (temporary name) of $U$ to be the set
$$
\tilde{U} := \bigcap_{\varphi \in V^*} \varphi^{-1}(\varphi(U)),
$$
where $V^* = \operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{C}(V,\mathbb{C})$ denotes the complex dual vector space of $V$. My question is thus:

> Can one characterize (set-theoretically, topologically) $\tilde{U}$ in more conventional terms?

I suspect that it may be related to one of the many convexity notions in Several Complex Variables, not only because of the analogy with the real case, but also because $\tilde{U}$ is the natural domain of existence for a certain *collection* of holomorphic maps (each of which can be extended beyond $\tilde{U}$, but not all in the same way).

*Feel free to add more appropriate tags.*

PS: Apologies for the "flood" of questions. I have gathered a few over the past year where I could use some clarity and only now have a bit more time on my hands to post them.